# Android Instant App

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

As shown in Google IO 2016 about Instant App, how to *enable* it in our application? And at which place or how to identify the screen for which Instant app should be enabled?
On top of this how difficult it would be for an application *without* **deep links** to convert it to one?

Comment: As mentioned multiple times during the demo, Android Instant App is not yet available. It will be delivered to developers "when it's ready".

Comment: So this will not be available soon enough?? Great so I have time for it, to make changes in my app

Answer (score 3):

Android Instant Apps is now open to all developers and the documentation is [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/index.html)

For App Links and enabling Instant Apps, watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Jg1D07NgeI&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc-odHd6XEaf7ykfsosYyCKp) video from Google I/O (disclosure: I am co-presenting).

Answer (score 3):

Basically, an [Instant App](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/overview.html?#apps-features) takes your installable app and divide it into ***feature modules***, each one has their own APKs and are accessible by URLs . To do that you'll have to make them addressable by using the [Android App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

As of today (2016 / 05 / 19), the instant app feature is not publicably available.

You can [visit an explanation page](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/index.html), click the "I am interested" link, and fill in the form. If your product is selected, they will help add the feature.

So far, the alternative is wait until its "polished" enough for market uses, and added to Android Studio, or Maven or any other repository, along with its documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of implementation it will depend on how modular your code is. Each instant app module has a limit of 4mb in size. You'll have to build some server side infrastructure if you want to persist the instant app session when the user downloads the full app.